# How to unit test dependend if statements?

Tags: php, unit-testing

following scenario:

```
 public class InputFilter(){

  public function isInputValid($input) : bool
  {
    $isValid = false;


    if($inputA && $inputB && $inputC){
       return true;     
    }

    if($inputD && $inputE){
      return true;     
    }

   ...

    return $isValid;
  }

}



 public Test(){

 //1. TestCase
 isInputValid_ValidInputABCGiven_ShouldReturnTrue(){
   $input[a => true, $b => true, c => true, d => false, e => false]
   assertSame(true, InputFilter->isInputValid, '')
 }

 //2. TestCase
 isInputValid_ValidInputBCGiven_ShouldReturnTrue{
  $input[a => false, $b => false, c => false, d => true, e => true]
  assertSame(true, InputFilter->isInputValid, '')
 }

}
```

i dont really know how to test this scenario probably.
Lets imagine first test case fails then i dont know if it is due to the fact the 
first if statement (a && b && c ) failed or the second if statement (d && e) has a problem. 
if the second test also fails, i would have no clue which of these statements caused the failure. The real problem has multiple of these if conditions...

is there any way to test the method, so that i know why the test failed ?

Comment: If statements never "have problems". They do exactly what they say. You don't test if statements. You test scenerios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If statements never "have problems". They do exactly what they say, 100% of the time. No need to test if statements.

You should however test individual scenarios.

For example:

```
function testResultReturnsFalseForADTrue
{
     $input[a => true, $b => false, c => false, d => true, e => false]
     assertFalse(InputFilter->isInputValid);
}
```

> if the second test also fails, i would have no clue which of these
>   statements caused the failure

It doesn't really matter which if statement caused the failure. If you're testing that input with A&B return false and it's returning true, you already have enough information.

There's no way to point out the exact line that's returning true, when you're expecting false or visa-versa.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of unit-testing (and testing in general) is to find bugs.  The approach is to exercise some code in a controlled way such that you have a clear expectation about how it behaves.  If during test execution the actual behaviour differs from the expected behaviour, you have to start your investigation where the problem is.  You may have found a bug - or possibly the test case is wrong !  This shows you can not even assume that the problem is actually in the code.  Often, in case of a failing test, debugging starts.

However, if you have code as you have shown, there should certainly be many more test cases.  The pattern of failing and succeeding tests can help you in your investigation.  It is a quality criterion of a test suite that you can easily track down a potential problem by looking at the list of test results.

Answer (score 0):

Make:

```
if($inputA && $inputB && $inputC){
       return true;     
    }
```

A function you call in your function. And then:

```
if($inputD && $inputE){
  return true;     
}
```

Another function you call.

And then make tests for those functions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These function would be private, because there would be no reason to make them visible for other classes. And from what i read testing private methods is considered as bad practice.